# fatal error : unmatched macro nesting?

Tags: assembly, macros, masm, irvine32

```
.686
.MODEL flat, stdcall
.STACK
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

 ReleaseArray MACRO ELem
REPT ELem
pop edi
ENDM
ENDM

det MACRO Dim
Local Start ,skip , L1,L2,Els ,Elm
;recives array in stack
;recives,dh num elements,dl dimisien
;produce det in eax

mov edx ,Dim  ;Elm = Dim*Dim
shl edx,1
mov Elm ,edx

push ebp
mov ebp,esp
Start: cmp Dim,1
jne els
mov eax,[ebp+4]
ret 4
els:
movzx ecx,Dim
xor esi,esi
xor eax,eax

L1: inc esi
push ecx
push esi
push eax
; push array
mov edi,dim
mov ecx , Elm-dim
L2: mov eax,dim
div edi
cmp esi , edx
Je skip
push [ebp+edi*4]
skip: inc edi
Loop L2
;=========
det Dim-1

imul [ebp+esi*4]

test esi,1
jne next
imul -1
next:
pop ebx
add eax,ebx
pop esi
pop ecx
loop L1
pop ebp
ReleaseArray Elm
ret
det ENDM



.DATA
Array dword 2500 dup(?)
String1 byte "Enter Dimension of matrix : " ,0
String2 byte "The Ditermenant of the matrix : " ,0
.CODE
main PROC
lea edx,String1
call writestring
call readint
mov ebx,eax
mul ebx
mov ecx,eax

xor edi,edi
Read: call Readint
push eax
mov Array[edi*4],eax
inc edi
loop Read

det ebx

push eax
mov cl,dl
xor edi,edi
column:
push ecx
mov cl,dl
Row:
mov eax,Array[edi*4]
call writeInt
inc edi
mov al,09h
call writechar
loop Row
call crlf
pop ecx
loop column

lea edx,String2
call writestring
pop eax
call writeint

call crlf
call waitmsg
exit
main ENDP

end main
```

Comment: A description of the code and an actual question would be nice ...

Comment: Please *at least* specify what assembler you are using

Answer (score 2):

bad:

```
ReleaseArray MACRO ELem
REPT ELem
pop edi
ENDM
ENDM
```

good:

```
ReleaseArray MACRO ELem
REPT ELem
pop edi
ReleaseArray ENDM         ; or just ENDM
```

Comment: I should write a script that whenever something fails to compile or assemble posts it to stack overflow with just the error message and then tries all the answers until it works. Great job finding the error, though :)

Comment: I can't because I'm not the one who asked the question.